# Angular HTTP request blocked - Showing mixed content

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, mixed-content

Angular HTTP request is blocked - Showing mixed content.

But when i'm accessing through browser URL, the content is showing.

The angular code is:

```
            $http.post('http://crms.ttteamthoi.in/get_timespent_br', {
                'from': '01/11/2015',
                'to': '25/11/2015'
            }, {
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                }
            })
            .then(function(response) {
              //code here
            }
```

The console error showing is:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://dash-thaidash.c9users.io/#/app/tonnage' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://crms.ttteamthoi.in/get_timespent_br'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Is this angular specific?

Comment: Do you have access to the controller code or is this a third party? It seems also that it has detected you are making and ajax request and does not accept it as secure...

Comment: I'm using this code in my controller. Does this ajax request only accepts secure ones?

Comment: I meant to ask if you have access to the code executed at 'http://crms.ttteamthoi.in/get_timespent_br' this route. It can check how the request is made and weather it is ajax or not and interpret this.

Comment: The server is written in asp.net. Unfortunately i dont have access to it. Its a third party application. But the link is working fine when accessing through browser and even in hurl.it

Comment: So it seems from the request and the answers that the thirs party does not accept the ajax request. This is sometimes implemented in sonata.

Comment: Thanks! that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem to be Angular specific. `crms.ttteamthoi.in` host is telling you that accepts only `https` requests, but you POST some data using `http` protocol. Try using `https`.

You can simulate http requests [here](https://www.hurl.it/).

Comment: I used https, but its a SSL ERROR.  im getting the content while accessing the link through browser.

Comment: Hey, i'm getting the response in Hurl.it.                                               Response:  Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 3373
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 16 Dec 2015 07:20:27 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Aspnet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Answer (score 2):

Problem Solved.

Server is asp.net application without SSL. The call was from https://c9.io which is secure. That was the mixed content error.

Changing the server application to SSL & then enabling CORS for content type did the trick.